# Override Hibernate caching strategy

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, annotations

I have two Java applications, **manager** and **server**, that use a shared library, **domain**. The Hibernate mapping is defined through annotations in the source of **domain**.

What I'm trying to accomplish is overriding the caching strategy of **server** to the 'read-only' caching strategy for some performance tests. Following [the annotations documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#xml-overriding), I came to the point where I was trying:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings 
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm orm_2_0.xsd"
  version="2.0">
    <entity class="com.example.data.Entity" metadata-complete="false">
       <cache usage="read-only"/>
    </entity> 
    ...
</entity-mappings>
```

Trying to mirror the annotation markup, mixing it with those instructions. Problem is, there's no allowed element *cache* for *entity*, and I get:

```
Error parsing XML (line66 : column 108): cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'cache'. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":description, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":table, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":secondary-table, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":primary-key-join-column, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":id-class, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":inheritance, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":discriminator-value, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":discriminator-column, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":sequence-generator, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":table-generator, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":named-query, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":named-native-query, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":sql-result-set-mapping, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":exclude-default-listeners, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":exclude-superclass-listeners, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":entity-listeners, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":pre-persist, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":post-persist, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":pre-remove, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":post-remove, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":pre-update, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":post-update, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":post-load, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":attribute-override, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":association-override, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":attributes}' is expected.
```

When, I try to return to the *hibernate-core* XML markup, I get errors that the **<class>** definition is incomplete, and I can't seem to find a **metadata-complete** analog. Does anyone know if what I'm trying to do is possible? And if so, what steps am I going to have to take? Thanks!